# Augmented Matrix Format

Tags: matrices

What does $1_{3}$? I believe it to be a $1\times 3$ matrix consisting of all $1$'s but I'm not certain that is correct.

$$M=\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 1 &-1 \\
1 & 2 & -1 \\
-1 & 2 & -2
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
M|1_3 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: A $3x3$ Identity Matrix. If you write $[M | I]$ (the Matrix $M$ is the LHS and $3x3$ identity is the RHS of the augmented matrix) and then get the LHS to be the identity matrix using Gaussian Elimination, the RHS becomes the matrix inverse. Example: https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/matrix-inverse-row-operations-gauss-jordan.html

Comment: The $1_3$ part is the augmented part and it's $3\times 3$? How would you have a solution after Gauss-Jordan?

Comment: See linked example - step by step example.

Comment: Of course! Thank you! I get it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1_3$ or $I_3$  refers to the $3 \times 3 $ identity matrix.
$$I_3 =\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 &0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0&1 \end{pmatrix}$$